# vector initialization failed in c++ class

Tags: c++

I tried to build a constructor for a hash table, but it failed.
Can anyone tell me what are the problems with the constructor codes?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct node {
string s;
node* next;
};

class QueryProcessor{

int bucket_count;
vector<node*> elems;

explicit QueryProcessor(int bucket_count) : bucket_count(bucket_count), elems(bucket_count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < bucket_count; ++i) {
        elems[i]->s = " ";
        elems[i]->next = NULL;
    }
} 
};

int main(){
int bucket_count;
cin >> bucket_count;
QueryProcessor proc(bucket_count);
}
```

Comment: `elems(bucket_count)`, note that all `bucket_count` elements in the vector are null pointers.

Comment: Didn't see any error in your code. What did the compiler say?

Comment: I have made my codes clear. Sorry about that.

Comment: The compiler said: `Exception thrown: read access violation.`

Answer (score 0):

You declare elems as a vector of pointers to node(s), but you never actually cut out any memory for them; so I think you are effectively dereferencing a NULL pointer- hence why it failed. Either cut out the memory or make elems a vector of just node(s).

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct node {
    std::string s;
    node* next;
};

int main() 
{
    // Constructs the container with 5 copies of a pointer to a node- note no actual memory is given to them yet.
    std::vector<node*> elems(5); // efectivly the same as your initalizer list for elems(bucket_count)
    std::cout<<"Size is: "<<elems.size()<<std::endl;
    if(elems[0] == NULL)
    {
        std::cout<<"elems[0] is a null pointer so dont use it!"<<std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"elems[0] has the string: "<< elems[0]->s <<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I think I didn't make my codes clear, so I updated my codes. The compiler said: `Exception thrown: read access violation.`

Comment: So i don't think the update you made is quite correct, because the ctor is effectively private. This is an example of what i was referring to if you want to keep a vector of pointers.

explicit QueryProcessor(int bucket_count) : bucket_count(bucket_count), elems(bucket_count) {
 for (int i = 0; i < bucket_count; ++i) {
  if(elems[i] == NULL) {
   cout<<"alocating memory for node: "<<i<<endl;
   elems[i] = new node;
   cout<<"string: "<<elems[i]->s<<" ptr: "<<elems[i]->next<<endl;
  } else {
   cout<<"initg node: "<<i<<endl;
   elems[i]->s = " ";
   elems[i]->next = NULL;
  }
 }
}